# Javascript Unexpected use of comma operator no-sequences warning

Tags: javascript, syntax, warnings

I have a react library which throw following warning.

```
Unexpected use of comma operator  no-sequences
```

It indicates the warning happens at 5 row, after **(_react.Component)** parameter.

> exports.default = function (_ref) {
>
> return function () {
>
> ```
>   var _class, _temp2;
>
>   return _temp2 = _class = function () {
>
>    }(_react.Component),
>        _class?.displayName = 'Resizable()', _temp2;
> ```
>
> };
> }

I simplfied the method. It's actually very long function.

How can i fix the warning? What is the proper syntax?

Comment: Not sure why `eslint` runs against the built codes?

Comment: Is the warning thrown by some linter? That looks like transpiled code. Why is the code style checks being run on that code?

Comment: it actually does not run in built codes. I cant understand the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

return a `<div>` tag to the rendered component e.g;

`const App=()=>{ return(<div>`
`<Header/> <Body/>`
`</div>`
);
}

`ReactDom.render(<App/>,document.getElementByid("root));`

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't forget to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for answering but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the issue? Also check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format code.